# Model with pm4py InvocationException( pydotplus.graphviz.InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found)

Tags: python, graphviz

I've installed pm4py through the terminal and attempted to run my code which creates a model from a dataframe but I get the error "InvocationException( pydotplus.graphviz.InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found)".   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUJFg.png)

I tried downloading graphviz separately, but it still doesn't work both through pip install and downloading from the website. In pip install it says Graphviz is already installed, and I just manually put the graphviz download file in program files. My code works until I try to map a model from the data, so I know that pm4py is working properly to some extent. How should I fix this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.